# Navigate from a screen in one navigator to a screen in another navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am using react-navigation v5.

In my app. I have two navigators, one stack navigator one drawer navigator:

```
const LoginStack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

I show either one based on login status:

```
{state.loggedIn? (
        <LoginStack.Navigator
          ...>
          <LoginStack.Screen
            name='login'
            component={LoginScreen}
          />
          <LoginStack.Screen
            name='register'
            component={RegisterScreen}
          />
        </LoginStack.Navigator>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Drawer.Navigator
            initialRouteName={Landing}
            drawerContent={props => <MyDrawerContent {...props} />}
           >
            <Drawer.Screen name="landing" component={LandingScreen} />
            ...
          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </>
      )}
```

As you can see above, if user is not logged in I show `LoginStack` navigator , otherwise I show `Drawer` navigator.  And if you look closely in the `Drawer.Navigator` part, I have declared my own drawer content `MyDrawerContent`.

Inside `MyDrawerContent`, I have a logout button. I would like to navigate user to the `LoginScreen` of `LoginStack`. I tried :

`<Button title="Logout" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('login')}/>`

But I get **error**: `The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator.`. Is it because I am navigating to a screen of another navigator which `MyDrawerContent` doesn't belong to?  How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you create two completely separate navigation trees, you cannot navigate between them because `login` screen is not registered, and thus not available, when you're in the `Drawer.Navigator`.

However, what you really want to do instead in your Logout button onPress, is change the `loggedIn` state to false. That will re-render the main app component and render the `LoginStack` instead. It's not very clear how you pass the `state` down the component tree so I can't provide a specific code example but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I have created a global context to host the state of login. The provider from that context wraps the whole application.

Comment: In that case, get the state from the context and update the `loggedIn` property.